# SVN says folder has been modified

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using SVN, When I do commit or "Check for modifications" (or svn status from command line), I get a list several folders.
Why do I see the folders that don't have any changed files in them? (There are files with changes that are set to be ignored )
Is there anyway to change this behavior?

Edit:
svn status output:

```
>svn status
 M      .
 M      src\com\proj\server
M       src\com\proj\server\DataAccessManager.java
M       src\com\proj\server\hibernate.cfg.xml
 M      war
 M      war\WEB-INF
```

and to see the diff for the war folder

```
>svn diff war
Index: war
===================================================================
--- war (revision 171)
+++ war (working copy)

Property changes on: war
___________________________________________________________________
Added: svn:ignore
## -0,0 +1 ##
+mycrm
Index: war/WEB-INF
===================================================================
--- war/WEB-INF (revision 171)
+++ war/WEB-INF (working copy)

Property changes on: war/WEB-INF
___________________________________________________________________
Added: svn:ignore
## -0,0 +1,2 ##
+classes
+deploy
```

Comment: Have you checked if there were really no changes to those files?
Have you checked if generated files from compilation are ignored? 
There is also something on the SVN settings about ignore whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is always a good idea to provide output and logs to avoid guessing on the part of those who try to understand your question.

That said, there are three possibilities:

(1) you've changed folder SVN properties (for example, during merging). In that case you'll see `M` in the **second** column (not first for regular changes).

(2) The files that were changed are versioned (already in the repository). You can't ignore versioned files (only unversioned ones). Unversioned files will be marked with `?`, if no `?` is present - the file is versioned.

(3) The default behavior for `svn status` is to show unversioned files. To disable - run it with `-q` option (i.e. `svn status -q`).

**Update:** With the logs provided it is clear that it's case (1) - SVN properties on your folders have changed. Run  `svn diff --depth=empty` on every directory that appears in the list to see what properties have changed (simple `svn diff` will also do the trick, but it will be harder to filter out the info you actually want).

Comment: I edited the question to add the output of svn status.  
It seems that the first case matches as I do have M in the second column.

Comment: I guess somewhere along the road I set some folder to be ignored and did not realize that that is a change that need to be committed.  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

What client to you use?

If use tortoiseSVN, and you add a file to ignore list - then the folder must be comitted (it's properties has changed).

Comment: Indeed adding a folder to an ignore list must be committed (unless it is "ignore on commit" which is local) to my defense I will say that it is hard to see, using tortoise svn, what were the changes to a folder and that is why I did not commit. because I always review the changes I made before committing.